# How to print the maximum number of long data type?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
printf("The maximum number limit of long type is %d.\n",LONG_MAX);
return 0;
}
```

The code above is okay, but when it is printed. It shows that the max number is 2147483647. The max number limimt for int. The actual value is 9223372036854775807. How do I get it display so?

Comment: How do you know that the actual value is 9223372036854775807?  Try adding `printf( "The size of a long type is %zu.\n", sizeof( long ) );`...

Comment: It is not unusual for `int` and `long` to have the same size.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` `%d` takes an `int`. This question really is "how do I print a `long int` with `printf`?".

The answer is to use `%ld` (and `%lld` for `long long int`).

Comment: I'm still displaying differently after changing it to %ld. Do I have to declare anything beforehand?

Comment: @cswannabe *I'm still displaying differently after changing it to %ld.*  Differently *how*?  Post what you're getting.

Comment: I would add that a compiler should have emitted a warning (gcc emit `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’`)